# Convert name as column and share remaining details across each new row

Tags: sql, postgresql

From this table, `name_info`

| value_id | value_type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | name | English_name |
| 100 | type | basic |
| 100 | name | French_name |
| 100 | name | Spanish_name |
| 100 | is_required | true |
| 100 | description | some description |

Expected output

| id | name | type | is_required | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | English_name | true | basic | some description |
| 100 | French_name | true | basic | some description |
| 100 | Spanish_name | true | basic | some description |

I need to span the `type`, `is_required` and `description` across different language names. (I have 30k data and looking for reliable way to do it.)

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [pivoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) similarly to the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761710/how-can-i-pivot-in-postgresql):

```sql
SELECT value_id,
    MAX("value") FILTER (WHERE value_type = 'type') AS "type",
    MAX("value") FILTER (WHERE value_type = 'is_required') AS is_required,
    MAX("value") FILTER (WHERE value_type = 'description') AS description
FROM vals
GROUP BY value_id;
```

```
 value_id | type  | is_required |   description
----------+-------+-------------+------------------
      100 | basic | true        | some description
```

Also I've done:

```sql
SELECT value_id, "value" FROM name_info WHERE value_type = 'name';
```

```
 value_id |    value
----------+--------------
      100 | English_name
      100 | French_name
      100 | Spanish_name
```

I've combined these via a join and some aliasing to give us:

```sql
SELECT nf.value_id AS id, nf."value" AS name,
  cols."type", cols.is_required, cols.description
FROM name_info AS nf
JOIN (
    SELECT value_id,
      MAX("value") FILTER (WHERE value_type = 'type') AS "type",
      MAX("value") FILTER (WHERE value_type = 'is_required') AS is_required,
      MAX("value") FILTER (WHERE value_type = 'description') AS description
    FROM name_info GROUP BY 1
) AS cols USING(value_id)
WHERE nf.value_type = 'name'
ORDER BY name;
```